# How to pass parameters to asmlinkage function?

Tags: c, kernel

I want to add a system call docs and I have one asmlinkage function. The function must take 2 parameters. These parameters are coming from the c docs which I calls system call. At below I showed the c docs :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc,char*argv[])
{
    long int amma = syscall(335,argc,argv);
    printf("System call functions returned %ld\n", amma);
    return 0;
}
```

As you see I want to pass `argc` and `argv` char array for making some file operations.

Firstly I wrote my asmlinkage function like that :

```
asmlinkage long function(int argc,char *argv[]){
  if(argc==2) 
       printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world"); // but it can not take argc
}
```

In addition I added to line to syscalls.h:

```
asmlinkage function(int,char*[]);
```

Then I compiled correctly but when I started to run my code in userspace my syscall killed.

I found a link in this website but I couldn't compile it. Topic owner used "SYSCALL_DEFINE" but I faced many code mistake which I could not understand.

Comment: The function's signature cannot fails by itself. Most likely the problem is how do you **use** the function's argument, but you don't show the function's **body**. We cannot help you to fix the code we don't see. See also [ask].

Comment: Thanks I gave details.

Comment: You say "my syscall killed". If you suspect that something wrong with the kernel code, then check `dmesg`. Does it show some error messages? If so, add them to the question post.